# Android Camera API - Weird zoom effect

Tags: android, camera, zooming

I am using the android camera API for a project I am working on at the moment and I came across a rather strange behavior. When I change the preview size to go to a higher resolution, I indeed get a much better quality preview but there is also this annoying zoom effect that occurs:
Say I am holding my device at 5 cm from a object in 1024x512, I can see it entirely. But if I change to 1920x1080, It's like I've zoomed into the object and I need to go further away to capture it entirely. Now that's a bit disappointing as I want a higher resolution to get more details of my object but if I have to go further away from it then the sensor is not sensible enough to get those details.
Is there something I misunderstood with the Camera API maybe?

Comment: How are you rendering the Camera preview frame?  (I'm wondering if it's not getting scaled to the window on the screen.)

Comment: Using a SurfaceView. I figured the API would set the SurfaceView's resolution according to the preview's resolution. Maybe not. Did not look into the options of the SurfaceView ...

Comment: TextureView will scale and generally behave like a View.  SurfaceView is just a transparent rectangle that sits on top of a layer handled directly by the surface compositor.  The TextureView doc (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) has an example of routing the camera preview to the View.

Comment: Hey sorry I wasn't around during the Xmas break. Thanks fadden for your answer. I went with a TextureView and I have no scaling effect anymore when I change the preview resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a bug on your side, or a bug (or a feature, if you like) of the camera on your device. To check, register for preview callback ([setOneShotPreviewCallback()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setOneShotPreviewCallback%28android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback%29)), save the buffers that you receive in same position for different resolutions, and compare the images.

From my personal experience, going from 4:3 to 16:9 resolution often reduces the field of view. But in your example, both settings keep same aspect ratio.

Comment: I've tried playing with different aspect ratios and turns out you were right. This is the reason to the effect I had noticed. Thanks

Comment: Hello, I also noticed this effect when I play the android system camera app. 4:3 ratio has a larger field than 16:9 at the same distance. But  I encounter a problem, I need this effect in my own app, but when I change the previewsize with API Camera.Parameters.setPreviewSize(int ,int), the field of preview do not change. How do you implement this effect?  Did I use the wrong method?

Comment: @dragonfly: I don't quite understand your question. There is no *contract* that controls the field of view for camera when its preview size changes. Please give more details. It will not cost you money to open a new question if you expect something beyond a one-liner reply.

Comment: @AlexCohn
Dear, please take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114191/field-of-camera-preview-is-smaller-if-i-use-the-way-of-preview-in-grifikas-cont