# EglCore.release() of grafika cause application to terminate on GT-I9500

Tags: android, opengl-es, grafika

I refered to ContinuousCaptureActivity of grafika to implement a demo which records video with MediaCodec. The demo worked fine in most cases, but crashed on my GT-I9500 device when back key pressed **( this crash is undetectable because we just assumed activity destroyed, I used 'adb shell ps' to check the existence of the demo process )**. Then I checked my source code repeatedly, found my code almost the same with ContinuousCaptureActivity of grafika. So I did the following things:

1. I installed apk of grafika in my GT-I9500 device and launched the ContinuousCaptureActivity, then I pressed the back key of my phone, but the application did not crash, it turned out that grafika worked fine.
2. I checked my code again and found nothing suspicious.
3. I created a new android project and copyed ContinuousCaptureActivity.java and other necessary files  such as AndroidManifest.xml, activity_continuous_capture.xml an so on from grafika to the new project. I modified the AndroidManifest.xml to make the ContinuousCaptureActivity the main activity. I compiled the code and installed the apk on my GT-I9500 device. **The same thing happened, the application crashed after I pressed the back key!!!**

**I am really confused with this problem, why did grafika work fine but the same code in a new project just crashed? Anyhow I believe there is a solution to the crash of my demo because grafika just worked fine.
Could anybody give me some advices?**

**Information that I can offer is as follows:**

1. I debuged the application and found the exact code which caused the crash, the code is https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/gles/EglCore.java#L191
2. The crash was very strage, there was no tombstone file generated and adb log is limited:

> 06-15 14:39:33.853 I/ActivityManager(  771): Process
>   com.example.grafikaaa (pid 13138) (adj 1) has died.
>
> 06-15 14:39:33.853 W/ActivityManager(  771): Force removing
>   ActivityRecord{42a876c8 u0
>   com.example.grafikaaa/.ContinuousCaptureActivity}: app died, no saved
>   state .... ....
>
> 06-15 14:39:33.903 D/Zygote  (  209): Process 13138 terminated by
>   signal (11)

3. Information of my device showed by GlesInfoActivity of grafika is as follows:

> ```
> ===== GL Information =====
>
>  vendor    : Qualcomm
>
>  version   : OpenGL ES 3.0 V@45.0 AU@  (CL@4169980)
>
>  renderer  : Adreno (TM) 320
>
>  extensions:
>
>    GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
>
>    GL_AMD_performance_monitor
>
>    GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400
>
>    GL_EXT_color_buffer_float
>
>    GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float
>
>    GL_EXT_debug_label
>
>    GL_EXT_debug_marker
>
>    GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer
>
>    GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query
>
>    GL_EXT_robustness
>
>    GL_EXT_sRGB
>
>    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
>
>    GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
>
>    GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV
>
>    GL_NV_fence
>
>    GL_OES_EGL_image
>
>    GL_OES_EGL_image_external
>
>    GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
>
>    GL_OES_depth24
>
>    GL_OES_depth_texture
>
>    GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map
>
>    GL_OES_element_index_uint
>
>    GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap
>
>    GL_OES_fragment_precision_high
>
>    GL_OES_get_program_binary
>
>    GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
>
>    GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
>
>    GL_OES_standard_derivatives
>
>    GL_OES_texture_3D
>
>    GL_OES_texture_float
>
>    GL_OES_texture_half_float
>
>    GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear
>
>    GL_OES_texture_npot
>
>    GL_OES_vertex_array_object
>
>    GL_OES_vertex_half_float
>
>    GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2
>
>    GL_QCOM_alpha_test
>
>    GL_QCOM_binning_control
>
>    GL_QCOM_driver_control
>
>    GL_QCOM_extended_get
>
>    GL_QCOM_extended_get2
>
>    GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode
>
>    GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering
>
>    GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering
>
>
>  ===== EGL Information =====
>
>  vendor    : Android
>
>  version   : 1.4 Android META-EGL
>
>  client API: OpenGL_ES
>
>  extensions:
>
>    EGL_ANDROID_image_native_buffer
>
>    EGL_EXT_create_context_robustness
>
>    EGL_KHR_create_context
>
>    EGL_KHR_fence_sync
>
>    EGL_KHR_gl_renderbuffer_image
>
>    EGL_KHR_gl_texture_2D_image
>
>    EGL_KHR_gl_texture_cubemap_image
>
>    EGL_KHR_image
>
>    EGL_KHR_image_base
>
>    EGL_KHR_lock_surface
>
>    EGL_KHR_wait_sync
>
>
>  ===== System Information =====
>
>  mfgr      : samsung
>
>  brand     : samsung
>
>  model     : GT-I9500
>
>  release   : 4.3
>
>  build     : JSS15J.I9500ZSUEMJ6
> ```

Comment: @fadden
Perhaps, nobody but you are able to figure out the reason.

Comment: Signal 11 indicates a native crash (segmentation fault). Something similar was reported previously, though the reporter didn't provide much in the way of details: https://github.com/google/grafika/issues/18 . My guess would be a Qcom driver bug. Not sure why the code would crash in one place but not another, though it's possible there's an edge case that is avoided when a different theme is chosen -- compare your AndroidManifest.xml for that Activity.

Comment: @fadden
 I have compared very carefully again. I was sorry to tell that the theme was the same with grafika. I have uploaded my code to github, could you please have a look at it?  The site is:https://github.com/yulf/demo1

Comment: I still think there is a solution to this crash, because grafika is ok.
@fadden

Comment: The *solution* would likely have to come from Samsung in the form of a driver fix. A work-around may be possible, but without a lot of experimentation it's hard to know what form that will take. As in the issue #18 linked earlier, the answer may be to avoid making the call that causes the crash (and live with the resource leak), at least on this specific device and version of Android.

Comment: @fadden
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664628/android-camera-api-weird-zoom-effect